# Getting Response.End() behavior in JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Thanks to everyone in advance -

I am aware of closing the jspwriter/outputstream and returning as a method to stop further execution in the main context. Has anyone found a way to stop execution outside of the main context? From my understanding of how jsp is 'compiled' etc I do not think this is possible, but I thought I should see if anyone has any clever solutions -

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I consider this to be an anti-pattern that should generally be avoided.  Just because ASP.NET lets you do this doesn't mean it's a good feature.  That being said, you can simulate the behavior by implementing a servlet request filter.  You would need to configure this filter in your `web.xml` to filter any requests handled by `JSPServlet` and other servlets that you would want to abort.

For this to work, any exception handling code you have would need to ignore or rethrow `ServletRequestAbortException`.

```
public class CancellableRequestFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (ServletRequestAbortException e) {
            //TODO: Maybe flush/close response here.
        }
    }

    public static void endRequest() {
        throw new ServletRequestAbortException();
    }

    public static class ServletRequestAbortException extends RuntimeException {
    }
}
```

Example call from a JSP:

```
<% com.your.pkg.CancellableRequestFilter.endRequest(); %>
```